# SharePoint views migration from classic to modern sites

Tags: sharepoint, office365

we are in the process of migrating data from a classic sharepoint to a modern sharepoint site, files and folders have been ok, also lists have moved, but we run into problems with sharepoint views and haven't find much documentation on best practices how to do this, only some comments that views should be re-created. Does anyone knows if this is the official best practice by microsoft? Thanks in advance for your feedback.

We have moved some views and also have fixed the indexes some to the point that they are functional. We are looking to get a clarification if we should be recreating them from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you want to migrate from SharePoint Server to SharePoint Online or from SharePoint Online to SharePoint Online?

From SharePoint Server to SharePoint Online, I suggest you use SPMT as a try.

From SharePoint Online to SharePoint Online, I suggest you use save document library as template feature in the SharePoint Online, should  select the Include Content check box, and the limit is 50MB and can’t be changed. If the document library exceeds 50 MB, you could consider to use three-party tool.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1194692/modern-sharepoint-online-custom-document-library-t